# Find the equation of the horizontal and vertical asymptotes

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the equations of the asymptotes for the following function: $$\frac{x^2 + 8}{x^2 - 9}$$

My solution is the asymptotes are first to find the vertical asymptotes. To do this, I have to find the value that make expression undefined. As a result, the vertical asymptotes are $x = -3$ and $x = 3$. To find the horizontal asymptotes, I have the compare the degrees of the numerator and the denominator, which result in $y = 1$

My question is, how do I find the equations for the vertical and horizontal asymptotes? Thank you.

Comment: ... you already did.

Comment: The equations are the ones you stated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An equation is a statement with an equal sign in it, so $x=-3$, $x=3$, and $y=1$ are all equations. Thus, you have already found the equations of the asymptotes. Good job!